# How can I pass 2 variables in URL using Angular?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app that uses a Python backend and a MongoDB. I am trying to get a single review through the URL that follows this:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/players/' + id + '/reviews/' + rid
```

In my `web.service.ts` I have the following func:

```
getReview(id: any, rid: any) {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/players/' + id + '/reviews/' + rid);
}
```

In my `review.component.ts` I have this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.player = this.webService.getPlayer(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
    this.player_review = this.webService.getReview(this.route.snapshot.params['id'], this.route.snapshot.params['rid']);
}
```

`this.player` get all the player data and `this.player_review` is suppose to bring back a single review.

The `this.player` works fine but I get this error for `this.player_review`:

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

Here is the URL: `http://localhost:4200/players/6194f873570f9ac9f081763e/reviews/61cde0f8daa68a9b80b3f3ad`

And here is a Postman screenshot of it working:

[image]

Why is this error happening?

Comment: can you show us the result of http://localhost:4200/players/6194f873570f9ac9f081763e/reviews/61cde0f8daa68a9b80b3f3ad using postman

Comment: The problem is in your template. You’re trying to do an ngFor on a single object. You need an itterable (like an array) to use ngFor.

Comment: Thank you @MikeOne ! My python code was returning: `return make_response(jsonify(player['review'][0]), 200)` so I changed it to: `return make_response(jsonify([player['review'][0]]), 200)` and It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getReview method returns object instead of an array. and you are using an ngFor to iterate player_review when it's not an array. that's why you got this error.

check the structure of the received data, Probably the array you want to iterate is contained into an attribute of the returned value of **this.webService.getReview**